# Is it Possible to Keep WebView Audio Running in Background on Android?

Tags: c#, audio, xamarin.android, android-webview, background-process

Is it possible to keep audio from a WebView, in particular, an embedded Webtorrent client (which plays video), running in the background on android?  I've seen conflicting answers on this, and I'm curious what you guys know about the topic.  I've seen some confirmed answers on ways to do it in android studio but not seen any for Xamarin.

I've been told that the WebView is considered a UI element; therefore, this makes it impossible to keep the video/audio running while in the background.  So if that's the case, do you think with some clever coding I could override the android OS to fool it into thinking that the WebView is still in the foreground?

I know that it's possible to keep the audio running using MediaPlayer, if for example say, you're playing an MP3.. So another possibility might be using a service to maintain audio focus; but then, would the video stop playing (seeing as how that doesn't fix WebView being a UI element)?

One other possibility would be porting the entire app into a service.. but I'm not sure if that's possible.  If I get an answer that it is, I'll do the work to make it happen.

I'm not looking for you guys to do the coding; I'm just looking for guidance on which method (if any) would be possible/plausible/most effective.

and here is some sample code I'm currently using to construct my WebView (not sure if that matters)

```
//what's on
[Activity]
//this class should be an aggregate subscription feed
public class WhatsOnActivity : Activity
{
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {


        WebView whatsOnWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewWhatsOn);

        whatsOnWebView.GoBack();
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.whatsOn);

        //declare webview and tell our code where to find the XAML resource
        WebView whatsOnWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewWhatsOn);

        whatsOnWebView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
        //set the webview client
        whatsOnWebView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        //load the 'whats on' url, will need webscript for curated subscribed feed
        whatsOnWebView.LoadUrl("https://www.bitchute.com/#listing-subscribed");
        //enable javascript in our webview
        whatsOnWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        //zoom control on?  This should perhaps be disabled for consistency?
        //we will leave it on for now
        whatsOnWebView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
        whatsOnWebView.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);
        //scrollbarsdisabled
        // subWebView.ScrollBarStyle = ScrollbarStyles.OutsideOverlay;
        whatsOnWebView.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;


    }
}
```

EDIT: Also, my opensource project can be found here
https://github.com/hexag0d/bitchute_mobile_android_a2

Thanks, in advance. =]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is quite late to answer this question, but the project I am working on is similar to this one.
I am currently working on this project by calling Activity with WebView through Foreground Service.

This is the code that calls Activity with Webview in Service.
Put this in the `onStartCommand()` of the Service.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(dialogIntent);
```